# I can't create this image overlay with svg

Tags: css, reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css

I am using react to create an image with a trapezoid-like background.
Here is what I have: [image]
[image: Mobile View]

But this approach ruins the view on mobile, due to overlap (min-w-[520px]). Is there a good way to make this all look good. Thanks in advance.

And here's the code:

```
<motion.div
variants={fadeIn("right", 0.6)}
initial="hidden"
whileInView="show"
viewport={{ once: true }}
className="bg-bottom bg-no-repeat bg-auto min-w-[520px]"
style={{
backgroundImage:
"url(https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/kudosite-5841e.appspot.com/o/templates_default_assets%2Ftemplate0%2Frounded-trapezoid.svg?alt=media&token=2976c52b-0ea6-4f9c-af09-42f95ed50d36)",
}}
>
<Image
   className="w-auto m-auto"
   src={image.image}
   width={500}
   height={500}
   />
</motion.div>
```

PS: Response doesn't have to be in tailwind, any CSS or any code in general is appreciated.

I've tried using absolute positioning, and using overlay background images, but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Have you tried using `background-size` property, like `bg-contain`? It should shrink the background image to the container size.

Comment: @o q, thanks for the reply. I've tried all sizing properties, doesn't seem to work. Any other suggestions